# rxjs/Subscription has no exported member 'Subscription'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, rxjs, rxjs-compat

I updated my angular project and all my dependencies to latest version. Without to much trouble I solved most of the dependency issues, but I'm still stuck on RxJS. Here is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "electron": "^1.8.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~6.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
```

I'm only importing two modules from RxJS:

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

They are both giving the same error:

```
    [ts] Module '"***/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported
 member 'Subscription'.
```

It's exactly the same for `fromPromise`. Here is the error message I'm getting from `Subscribtion.d.ts` (I have not modified the code in any way)

[image]

UPDATE:

The answers bellow solved the issue with Subscription but `fromPromise` still gives the same issue even though it's exported correctly:

`export * from 'rxjs-compat/observable/fromPromise';`

[image]

Comment: In your code you're importing from `rxjs` but in the image you have `rxjs-compat`

Comment: The new version of RxJs has a different way of importing and piepeable operators. You need to install rxjs-compat for backwards compatibility and then gradually upgrade to the new version. [Here is the migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)

Comment: @AdrianFâciu, the link is dead

Comment: solved it for me :  `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is a lot of breaking changes with RxJS 6. For example, prototype methods as

```
myObservable.map(data => data * 2)
```

won't work anymore and must be replaced by

```
myObservable.pipe(map(data => data * 2))
```

All details can be found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

---

Until you have fixed all breaking changes, you can make your old code work again with `rxjs-compat` (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/compat).

> This package is required to get backwards compatibility with RxJS
>   previous to version 6. It contains the imports to add operators to
>   `Observable.prototype` and creation methods to `Observable`.

Type this to install it:

```
npm install -s rxjs-compat
```

Comment: broken link ! https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 12):

I hope your problem will resolve using this below statement
 **`import Subscription from 'rxjs'`**

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it with this:

import {**from**} from 'rxjs';

And, instead of:
return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

Now just do:

return **from**(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

The same applies to Observable.of

Answer (score 0):

afaik Angular 6 and rxjs 6 are not already compatible, for the compatibility  they created https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat you have to install

[UPDATE]
fromPromise is now "from".
see here : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3525

Comment: Angular 6 and RxJs 6 are quite compatible. One needs to change the imports and use pipeable operators.

Comment: I saw a lot of issues on github/stackoverflow (like here) but mostly with the beta/rc version , my bad

Comment: If this answer is no longer relevant/incorrect you can delete it (up to you), especially since OP has noted that they're using `rxjs-compat` already.