# ng serve run in import module errors ...has no exported member

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, npm-start

I have only been working on ASP.Net Core for a few days and after two days of unsuccessful attempts my nerves are on the ground.

I am trying to run an ASP.Net Core Boilerpplate from here https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates. I follow the instructions exactly but the only progress is that the error messages have changed:

my Terminal output:

```js
> surveydpo@4.7.1 start D:\Benutzer\Admin\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2019\SurveyDPO\5.4.0\angular
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.07 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 154 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 1.15 MB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-04-16T19:48:33.963Z - Hash: 1f1c667e422cd368a343 - Time: 17020ms

ERROR in ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.component.d.ts:3:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.

3 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-daterangepicker.component.d.ts:3:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.

3 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-locale.service.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

1 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
           ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-locale.service.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.

2 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/state.class.d.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.

4 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/state.class.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

5 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
           ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/store.class.d.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

4 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
           ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/store.class.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observer"' has no exported member 'Observer'.

5 import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/mini-ngrx/store.class.d.ts:6:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Operator"' has no exported member 'Operator'.

6 import { Operator } from 'rxjs/Operator';
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/draggable-item.service.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.

1 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
           ~~~~~~~
../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.component.d.ts:7:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/Benutzer/Admin/Dokumente/Visual Studio 2019/SurveyDPO/5.4.0/angular/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.

7 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.       

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/Observer.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observer'.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observer';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/Operator.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Operator'.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Operator';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Subject';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.   

1 export * from 'rxjs-compat/Subscription';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ 
**
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "surveydpo",
  "version": "4.7.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --hmr",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "lint": "tslint --force --project src/tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.4",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/jquery.blockui": "0.0.28",
    "@types/jquery.validation": "^1.16.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
    "abp-ng2-module": "^5.1.1",
    "abp-web-resources": "^5.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-countto": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "node-waves": "^0.7.5",
    "push.js": "1.0.9",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.4",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "nswag": "^13.0.6",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "surveydpo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              },
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr-client.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/assets/fonts/roboto/roboto.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css",
              "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/materialize.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/style.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/themes/all-themes.css",
              "src/shared/core.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js",
              "node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.js",
              "node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js",
              "node_modules/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js",
              "node_modules/spin.js/spin.min.js",
              "node_modules/spin.js/jquery.spin.js",
              "node_modules/push.js/bin/push.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js",
              "node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
              "node_modules/morris.js/morris.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.time.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.toastr.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.spin.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.sweet-alert.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.moment.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/admin.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/demo.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/jquery.validate.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "hmr": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "surveydpo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "surveydpo:build:production"
            },
            "hmr": {
              "browserTarget": "surveydpo:build:hmr"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "surveydpo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js",
              "node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.js",
              "node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js",
              "node_modules/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js",
              "node_modules/spin.js/spin.min.js",
              "node_modules/spin.js/jquery.spin.js",
              "node_modules/push.js/bin/push.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js",
              "node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
              "node_modules/morris.js/morris.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.time.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.toastr.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.spin.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.sweet-alert.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.moment.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/admin.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/demo.js",
              "src/bsb-theme/js/jquery.validate.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/fonts/roboto/roboto.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css",
              "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/materialize.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/style.css",
              "src/bsb-theme/css/themes/all-themes.css",
              "src/shared/core.less"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              },
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr-client.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "surveydpo-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "surveydpo:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "surveydpo",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AbpModule } from '@abp/abp.module';

import { ServiceProxyModule } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxy.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';

import { HomeComponent } from '@app/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '@app/about/about.component';
import { TopBarComponent } from '@app/layout/topbar.component';
import { TopBarLanguageSwitchComponent } from '@app/layout/topbar-languageswitch.component';
import { SideBarUserAreaComponent } from '@app/layout/sidebar-user-area.component';
import { SideBarNavComponent } from '@app/layout/sidebar-nav.component';
import { SideBarFooterComponent } from '@app/layout/sidebar-footer.component';
import { RightSideBarComponent } from '@app/layout/right-sidebar.component';
// tenants
import { TenantsComponent } from '@app/tenants/tenants.component';
import { CreateTenantDialogComponent } from './tenants/create-tenant/create-tenant-dialog.component';
import { EditTenantDialogComponent } from './tenants/edit-tenant/edit-tenant-dialog.component';
// roles
import { RolesComponent } from '@app/roles/roles.component';
import { CreateRoleDialogComponent } from './roles/create-role/create-role-dialog.component';
import { EditRoleDialogComponent } from './roles/edit-role/edit-role-dialog.component';
// users
import { UsersComponent } from '@app/users/users.component';
import { CreateUserDialogComponent } from '@app/users/create-user/create-user-dialog.component';
import { EditUserDialogComponent } from '@app/users/edit-user/edit-user-dialog.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './users/change-password/change-password.component';
import { ResetPasswordDialogComponent } from './users/reset-password/reset-password.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    TopBarLanguageSwitchComponent,
    SideBarUserAreaComponent,
    SideBarNavComponent,
    SideBarFooterComponent,
    RightSideBarComponent,
    // tenants
    TenantsComponent,
    CreateTenantDialogComponent,
    EditTenantDialogComponent,
    // roles
    RolesComponent,
    CreateRoleDialogComponent,
    EditRoleDialogComponent,
    // users
    UsersComponent,
    CreateUserDialogComponent,
    EditUserDialogComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    ResetPasswordDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    AbpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceProxyModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxPaginationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
    // tenants
    CreateTenantDialogComponent,
    EditTenantDialogComponent,
    // roles
    CreateRoleDialogComponent,
    EditRoleDialogComponent,
    // users
    CreateUserDialogComponent,
    EditUserDialogComponent,
    ResetPasswordDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I would be very happy if someone can help me with this,

Comment: Can you try update the ngx-bootstrap and rxjs packages to the latest versions

Comment: I tried to update most of the modules but got errors like thi:s:
PS D:\Benutzer\........ 2019\SurveyDPO\5.4.0\angular> npm update ngx-bootstrap
PS D:\Benutzer\Admin\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2019\SurveyDPO\5.4.0\angular> npm update rxjs
PS D:\Benutzer\Admin\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2019\SurveyDPO\5.4.0\angular> npm install -g rxjs
+ rxjs@6.5.5
added 2 packages from 7 contributors in 5.094s
PS D:\Benutzer\Admin\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2019\SurveyDPO\5.4.0\angular> npm install  ngx-bootstrap        
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of breaking changes with RxJS 6. 
[Check this like for more details](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)
Until you have fixed all breaking changes, you can make your old code work again with [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) or consider downgrade to RxJS 5.

See [rxjs/Subscription has no exported member 'Subscription'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176029/rxjs-subscription-has-no-exported-member-subscription).

Comment: Great, i will follow your advice and give a feedback soon, Thank you